# google analytics code working on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, google-analytics

I m new to **Google analytics**, I bind click event with google analytics
**on click of some  tag** I call ga(create ) and ga(send).

But this **code only work in on firefox, not on chrome?**

when I use the same site on firefox it gave me result in analytics but on chrome is not showing any result.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Could you add the code you have used so we can replicate and help?

Comment: $(".dropdownExpansionDiv a.topEvent").on("click",function(e) {var nameofevent = $(this).text();
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx');
ga('send', 'event',nameofevent,'click','visitor looked'+nameofevent+' ');}); 
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

Comment: @fvbuendia Sorry for messy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, I see it hard to know the issue, but some things that you should consider:

1) Append the click event only on document load. This will prevent errors if the element was not loaded.

2) Create the Analytics instances immediately after instead of doing it on click. Creating the instance does not send any data to be tracked and you ensure it's ready for when you send the click event.

3) Ensure that there are no other scripts causing issues. If one script is faulty the execution will be paused. Check the console for errors.

This seems to work for me. Try this code with your UA and check the realtime section on Analytics.

```js
// Load analytics.
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

// Initialise analytics.
ga('create', 'UA-123456789'); 

// Append click options on load.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdownExpansionDiv a.topEvent").on("click", function(e) {
    var nameofevent = $(this).text();
    ga('send', 'event', nameofevent, 'Click', 'Visitor looked ' + nameofevent);
    console.log('send', 'event', nameofevent, 'Click', 'Visitor looked ' + nameofevent);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdownExpansionDiv">
  <a class="topEvent">Test</a>
</div>
```